# How to show "only mails with attachments" in MacOS Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave, search, attachments

In the search box in the top right of Mail, I enter the search term but then want to restrict the results in the same way you can with Outlook on PC "has attachment" to only show those mails that include the search term AND have an attachment.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start typing "attachment" in the same search box and then select it when the prompt comes up. It will then show only those mails that have attachments.